# How to remove apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2

How can I remove apache from my server?I'm using Ubuntu 9 64bit, the apache2 came preinstalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command like this may get rid of everything.

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep apache | xargs apt-get --yes apt-get purge
```

You probably should run `dpkg --get-selections | grep apache` this command first to see the list of packages that will be uninstalled so you can be sure the grep is selecting the right things.

Answer (score 5):

As root (or via sudo): `$ apt-get remove apache2`

Comment: Nope, doesn't work

Comment: Why "doesn't it work"? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me: `aptitude purge ~i~napache`